# How do you throw a ball of sand at someone?

Tags: die2nite

If I am outside of town, I can click the ball, but it just does nothing. How do I throw it at someone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least in the german version of Die2Nite the sandballs were only enabled for a short time, after that they don't work anymore. I assume they're now also disabled in the english version.

Answer (score 3):

I think they were analogous to snow balls, which implies they are probably a special Christmas-related event.